# capybaraのhave_contentなどで、含まれていてほしい単語の数を指定したい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

例えば、ページ内に

```
あいうえお
単語
かきくけこ
単語
```

とあった場合、capybaraで

```
expect(page).to have_content('単語')
```

とした場合、マッチしますがこの'単語'の数をテストすることは可能でしょうか？

自分の場合、ひとつの'単語'のみ含まれていてほしいというようにしたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`expect(page).to have_content('単語', count: 1)`

でいかがでしょうか？

have_xxx には引数が渡せるようです。

[capybara/matchers.rb at master · jnicklas/capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb#L432-L449)

下記に一部を抜粋します。

```
  #     @option options [Integer] :count (nil)     Number of times the text is expected to occur
  #     @option options [Integer] :minimum (nil)   Minimum number of times the text is expected to occur
  #     @option options [Integer] :maximum (nil)   Maximum number of times the text is expected to occur
  #     @option options [Range]   :between (nil)   Range of times that is expected to contain number of times text occurs
```